# ¿Como puedo eliminar los datos que no coinciden de una tabla en MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Mi problema es que quiero que comparando dos tablas que tienen los mismos campos, si en la segunda tabla no hay un id que coincida con la primera tabla lo elimine de la base de datos de MySQL.

Mis tablas son las siguientes:

```
Tabla 1:  
ID    NOMBRE  
1     Oriol  
2  Ricard

Tabla 2:   
ID  NOMBRE  
1   Oriol
```

Al comparar estas dos tablas quiero que en la primera tabla solo aparezca el que tiene el mismo id que en la segunda tabla teniendo este resultado:

```
Tabla 1:   
ID  NOMBRE  
1   Oriol

Tabla 2:   
ID  NOMBRE  
1   Oriol
```

Me gustaria saber qué codigo SQL necesito para poder hacer mi tarea.

La cosa sería más o menos de este estilo:

```
ELIMINAR DE Tabla 1 AQUELLOS REGISTROS QUE NO EXISTAN EN LA Tabla 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM TABLA1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLA2)
```

Saludos! ;)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha servido!!! :D

Comment: ¿Y si quiero hacer un INSERT de los datos nuevos que hay en la tabla 2 respecto a la tabla 1?

Comment: En una sola query? o con programación?

Comment: En una sola query si puede ser.

Comment: No voy a decir que no se pueda, por que seguro que alguien se le ocurre, pero a mi no se me ocurre como hacerlo en una sola sentencia.

Comment: espera que si se me ocurre una forma

Comment: Osea la idea es en una sentencia hacer el DELETE y en otra el INSERT.

Comment: seria algo asi: insert into TABLAX values (select group_concat('(',CAMPO1, ',', CAMPO2, ')') from TABLA2 where ID not in (SELECT ID FROM TABLA1))

Comment: No esta probado! , pero seguro que lo sacas! ;)